# Is there a solution of $2^n+3^m-5^k=1$

Tags: number-theory

I dont know if there is a solution of $$2^n+3^m-5^k=1$$ especialy if the values of $n$, $m$ and $k$ integer numbers greater than $100$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$ 2^n $ is even, $3^m $ is odd, $5^k+1 $ is even, hence there cannot be any solutions (except m=k=n=0).